# How can I output some results from a Netlogo program into a txt file?

Tags: simulation, netlogo

I want to put the results of `output-print count turtles with [color = black]` into a txt file, how can I manage to do it please ? 
The thing is a want to create a database that will write the resulats in the same file after every try

Comment: See the [BehaviorSpace Guide](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/behaviorspace.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can read the section on output in the Programmer's Guide.

```
file-open "myfile.txt"  ;; possibly in SETUP, only needed once
...
file-print count turtles with [color = black]   ;;probably in GO
...
file-close              ;; possibly in a WRAPUP procedure, only needed once
```